# Invalid use of argument matchers

Tags: java, mockito

The simple test case below is failing with an exception.

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:
Invalid use of argument matchers! 3 matchers expected, 2 recorded:
```

I am not sure what is wrong

```
@Test
public void testGetStringTest(){
    final long testId = 1;
    String dlrBAC = null;
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = mock(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.class);
    when(this.dao.getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate()).thenReturn(jdbcTemplate);
    when(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
        anyString(), 
        any(SqlParameterSource.class), 
        String.class
    )).thenReturn("Test");
    dlrBAC =  dao.getStringTest(testId);
    assertNotNull(dlrBAC);
}
```

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Mockito requires you to either use only raw values or only matchers when stubbing a method call. The full exception (not posted by you here) surely explains everything.

Simple change the line:

```java
when(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
    anyString(),
    any(SqlParameterSource.class), 
    String.class
)).thenReturn("Test");
```

to

```java
when(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
    anyString(), 
    any(SqlParameterSource.class), 
    eq(String.class)
)).thenReturn("Test");
```

and it should work.

Comment: add `import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;`

Comment: above change gives compile time error as                                 "The method eq(Class<String>) is undefined for the type test class

Comment: add the static import I just mentioned

Comment: Hope my understanding is correct: If you are using any matcher for any 1 argument then you need to use matcher for all other arguments as well for a method or do not use matcher at all and pass actual value/object.

Comment: Very old post, but for the Scala programmers that end up here (like myself), you'll find out that adding `import org.mockito.Mockito._` and then calling `eq(classOf[String])` won't work. The solution is to use the full path of the `eq()` function: `org.mockito.Matchers.eq(classOf[String]))` as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29524445/5420229).

Comment: (scala) org.mockito.Matchers is deprecated, alternative is 
 org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.eq

Comment: I'm getting this error using none of "real value", only matchers static functions.

Answer (score 0):

For me I was using EasyMock and it was the wrong import. Make sure you have the correct imports of (anyString, any, anyInt).

Answer (score 0):

I was having Autowired annotation on the bean I was trying to mock. But, it should have been MockBean annotation.