# Match classes in Scala with Mockito

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mockito

I'm trying to mock up a Spark context to return a mocked RDD when `newAPIHadoopFile` is called.

I've set it up as follows:

```
val mockedOuterRdd = mock[RDD[(NullWritable, MyProtobuf)]]

mockedSc.newAPIHadoopFile(anyString, anyObject(),classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable],
  classOf[MyProtobuf],anyObject()) returns mockedOuterRdd
```

This is fine in the compiler, but when I run it I get

```
Invalid use of argument matchers!
5 matchers expected, 3 recorded:
-> at ...
This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
```

Is there a way I can use something like `eq(...)`(which I've tried and doesn't work) with `classOf[...]`?

I've tried using `anyObject` for the classes, but it infers the type parameter for the RDD from these so they need to be right.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Have you tried isA ?
http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/Matchers.html#isA(java.lang.Class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`eq` works for me, however I am guessing you might have left out some details of your testing framework. I used `scalatest` and when I tried to use `eq` it kept yelling at me for returning a `boolean` instead of a `Class`. However, there is a generic `eq` that should take over. So, the **solution** is to use the full path:

```
mockedSc.newAPIHadoopFile(anyString, anyObject(),
  org.mockito.Matchers.eq(classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable]), 
  org.mockito.Matchers.eq(classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable]), anyObject())
```

Comment: I was getting the error about it returning a Boolean when I tried it too - this sorts it out. Thanks

Comment: Thanks! I has the same problem and using the entire path org.mockito.Matchers.eq worked for me too! I still don't understand why it doesn't work using it without the full import path...