# Mockito Error :.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: Invalid use of argument matchers

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

```
 @Test
@DisplayName("Success scenario for Card Replace for Lost")
void testcardReplaceLostSuccess() throws Exception {
    final CardReplaceRqst cardReplaceRqst = mockCardReplaceRequest("Lost");
    when(cardBlockService.sendBlockRequest(cardReplaceRqst)).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(any(), HttpStatus.OK));
    when(cardReplaceService.replaceCard(ArgumentMatchers.eq(cardReplaceRqst), any(CardType.class)))
        .thenReturn(mockCardReplaceResponse());

    mockMvc
        .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(REPLACE_REQUEST_URL).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .content(TestUtils.toJson(cardReplaceRqst)).characterEncoding("utf-8"))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk()).andExpect(jsonPath("$.successCode").value("Success"));
}
```

When I run this code, I get the below error.

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:
```

Invalid use of argument matchers!
2 matchers expected, 3 recorded:

Any suggestions?

p.s. I had to add ArgumentMatcher.eq() because of a sonar rule "Add an "eq()" argument matcher on this parameter."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid use of argument matchers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468456/invalid-use-of-argument-matchers)

Answer (score 0):

Using `any()` in the response `thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(any(), HttpStatus.OK));` is illegal and causes a mess with subsequent stubbing

See [Argument Matchers](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#argument_matchers)

> Matcher methods like any(), eq() do not return matchers. **Internally, they record a matcher on a stack and return a dummy value (usually null).** This implementation is due to static type safety imposed by the java compiler. **The consequence is that you cannot use any(), eq() methods outside of verified/stubbed method.**

Comment: thanks! Any reason why any() should be avoided in the .thenReturn() method?

Comment: See updated answer